# Nginx rewrites being ignored

Tags: nginx

I am trying to rewrite the following in an nginx server block.

/#/dmles/login/groupInvitation /login/groupInvitation

I have tried using both regex and a rewrite without using regex. I have enabled rewrite logging in nginx as well. The rewrite log never gets any entries.

I have tried the following:

rewrite ^/#/dmles/login/groupInvitation /login/groupInvitation last;

rewrite ^/#/dmles/(.*)  $1 last;

With either of these 2 or no rewrite in place at all it gets changed to /login/loginForm. The rewrite if working properly will bypass the loginForm and go to the groupInvitation form instead.

Nginx version is 1.17.6 running on redhat linux 7.6.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: The part of the URL from `#` onwards is the fragment and is never sent to the server, so Nginx never sees it. It's for client side scripts only.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith.